# Почему может не поддерживаться тип курсора?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

```
statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.FETCH_UNKNOWN, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
```

получаю ошибку:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The cursor type is not supported.
```

помогите понять как решить.

Comment: Потому что ваша СУБД не поддерживает такой тип курсора. Читать раздел features описания СУБД.

Comment: Как решить - примените другой тип курсора. По идее он должен быть UPDATABLE и SCROLLABLE. Попробуйте подобрать или найти пример с использованием MSSQL и Java

Answer (score 2):

Помогло вот что, воспользовался третьим конструктором:

```
conecction.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.HOLD_COURSOR_OVER_COMMIT);
```

Есть еще вот такие вспомагательные методы интерфейса *DatabaseMetaData*:

*supportsResultSetType(Int)* - дает понять реализует ли драйвер JDBC тот или иной тип выборки.

*supportsResultSetCuncurrency(Int)* - дает понять используется ли тот или иной режим драйвером.

*getResultSetHoldability(Int)* - так же дает понять о наличии третьего режима в драйвере JDBC

Надеюсь кому то будет полезно!

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet.FETCH_UNKNOWN` означает, что направление прохода курсора не определено. Между тем в [списке поддерживаемых курсоров](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms378405(v=sql.110).aspx) сказано, что `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` -- это "Однопроходный, обновляемый" курсор. По всей видимости, драйверу не понравилось сочетание `FETCH_UNKNOWN` и `CONCUR_UPDATABLE`. Попробуйте заменить `FETCH_UNKNOWN` на `FETCH_FORWARD`.